# Como manter o mesmo objeto entre as requisições no Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Tô querendo ir adicionando os itens ao mesmo objeto Pedido dinamicamente, mas sempre ta instanciando um novo Pedido.

```
@GetMapping("/novo")
public ModelAndView preSalvar(@ModelAttribute ("pedido") Pedido Pedido){
    List<Produto> produtos= produtoService.recuperar();
    List<Mesa> mesas= mesaService.recuperar();
    ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView("/pedido/add");
    Date date=new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm ");
    String data= sdf.format(date);
    model.addObject("mesas",mesas);
    model.addObject("produtos", produtos);
    model.addObject("data",data);
    return model;
}


@GetMapping("/{codigo}/additem")
public String add (@PathVariable long codigo,@ModelAttribute ItemPedido itemPedido, @ModelAttribute Pedido pedido, BindingResult bindingResult){
    Produto produto= produtoService.recuperarPorId(codigo);
    itemPedido.setProduto(produto);
    itemPedido.setQuantidade(1);
    itemPedido.setPrecoUnit(produto.getPreco());
    pedido.addItem(itemPedido);
    System.out.println(pedido.toString());
    System.out.println(itemPedido);
    return "pedido/add";
}
```

```html
<form >
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Preço</th>
                <th>Quantidade</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr th:each="produto : ${produtos}">
                <td >
                    <a th:text="${produto.nome}" >nome</a>
                </td>
                <td th:text="${produto.descricao}">descricao</td>
                <td th:text="${'R$ ' + produto.preco}">preco</td>
                <td><input class="form-control col-md-2" id="quantidade" type="number" value="1" min="1"/><a id="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" th:href="@{/pedidos/{codigo}/additem(codigo=${produto.codigo})}" >Add</a></td>


            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toda vez que você vai incluir um item no pedido você chama o serviço de inclusão pra atualizar o pedido?
 Dessa forma sua aplicação vai cair muito na performance.
 Eu sugiro que você controle sua lista de itens no front-end, basicamente adiciona e exclui itens na lista e depois um botão de "check out" ou finalizar pedido, aí sim você cria seu pedido com os itens. Exemplo:

```
   @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> insert(@Valid @RequestBody Pedido obj) {
        obj = pedidoService.insert(obj);
        URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(obj.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
    }

   @Transactional
    public Pedido insert(Pedido obj) {
        obj.setId(null);
        obj.setInstante(new Date());
        obj.setCliente(clienteService.find(obj.getCliente().getId()));
        obj.getPagamento().setEstado(EstadoPagamento.PENDENTE);
        obj.getPagamento().setPedido(obj);
        if (obj.getPagamento() instanceof PagamentoComBoleto) {
            PagamentoComBoleto pagto = (PagamentoComBoleto) obj.getPagamento();
            boletoService.preencherPagamentoComBoleto(pagto, obj.getInstante());
        }
        obj = pedidoRepository.save(obj);
        pagamentoRepository.save(obj.getPagamento());
        for (ItemPedido ip : obj.getItens()) {
            ip.setDesconto(0.0);
            ip.setProduto(produtoService.find(ip.getProduto().getId()));
            ip.setPreco(ip.getProduto().getPreco());
            ip.setPedido(obj);
        }
        itemPedidoRepository.saveAll(obj.getItens());
        return obj;
    }
```

Espero que isso tenha te ajudado.

Comment: Controlar a lista de itens com javascript? com jquery da pra fazer isso?